# Undefined table data

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CI 2.1.0 with HMVC. I am going to implement pagination in view part. But I get **'Undefined table data'** error. It displays paging number (1,2,3,..) but does not display records.

**My code is :**

included library for pagination : 
**$this->load->library('table');**

**controller**

```
$data['title'] = "Test Events";
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/index.php/events/test/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->eventModule->countRow();
$config['per_page'] = '3';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$config['records'] = objectsIntoArray($this->eventModule->get_record($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3)));

$data['main_content'] = 'test';       
$this->load->view('event/template', $data);
```

**view**

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate('records'); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Thank you for support.

Comment: if you want someone help you accept the answer of questions that you give first.

Comment: @safarov, it's not that what you thought. I did but didn't see any change. So I tried to make clear on my directory structure.. anyway thanx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the solution. It's silly mistake at

**$config['records'] = objectsIntoArray($this->eventModule->get_record($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3)));**

It should be *$data* instead of *$config*

**$data['records'] = objectsIntoArray($this->eventModule->get_record($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3)));**